# Files Connect: How to create SharePoint folder?

Tags: apex, chatter, files, connect-api

## Business Use Case

As accounts in Salesforce reach certain status then business wants new SharePoint folder to be created with same name and as users add files to that account then those files would be synced over to SharePoint in the appropriate folder.

## Current Setup

I've setup a SharePoint auth. provider and external data source in my Salesforce sandbox. I can successfully browse my SharePoint site and navigate folders and view files. I can use the `ConnectApi` in Apex to create new files in SharePoint.

## Question

How can I create new **folders** in SharePoint via the `ConnectApi` in Apex?

As far as I can tell, since `ConnectApi.ContentHub.getAllowedItemTypes` only returns to me a `ConnectApi.ContentHubAllowedItemTypeCollection` with one `ConnectApi.ContentHubItemTypeSummary` record that represents a **file** then my only recourse to create **folders** is to make http callouts from apex to the SharePoint REST API directly rather than use the `ConnectApi` in Apex.

I much rather prefer to use the `ConnectApi` in Apex as its a nicer abstraction of the actual SharePoint / Box / Google Drive APIs than making the http requests myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of May 25, 2017, the ConnectApi in Apex does not support creating folders.

Confirmed by Salesforce product managers [Arnab Bose](https://twitter.com/ArBose/status/867837347894763521) and [Haris Ikram](https://twitter.com/HarisIkramH/status/867837902838939649).

In the meanwhile, please vote for this idea: [Ability to create Folders using Files Connect Repository Resources](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CRrzQAG)

[image]